# Best method for high speed BLE data transfer to iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have developed Apps for both Android and iOS (in Swift) to read 100Hz acceleration data from a third party sensor, successfully, using the provided SDK's. Now the sensor has now been withdrawn from manufacturer.

I have found an alternate third party sensor which works fine on Android, but I am struggling to get it to work with iOS 15.6. I am using the manufacturer's SDK written in Obj-C. Unfortunately, I am new to Obj-C and Swift.  They are using the NotificationCenter.default to send the received data to the Swift UI. The data is not received regularly as expected and seems to come in packets, some of which are repeated. This makes the data unusable. It must be able to read at 10msecs frequency.

Is the problem likely to be due to the Notification Center or async threads?
Any thoughts on which direction to focus on or fix would be great.

Comment: Also, any suggested alternate approaches or methods would be great. Thanks

Comment: "Is the problem likely to be due to the Notification Center " -- No. NotificationCenter, although an odd choice for something like this, is not prone to bugs and is well battle-tested. Async threads? Maybe in terms of when they're delivered, but it wouldn't cause duplicates. I suggest you include your actual code with information about the actual device you're using -- otherwise, everything is pure speculation.

Comment: My concern was whether the Notification Center would be too slow for the throughput requirement. Re providing the code that communicates to the device, it is in a third party SDK. The sensor is a Moko W6 Bluetooth beacon with LIS2DH accelerometer. This works fine with my Android APP.

Comment: Notification Center is a synchronous, in-memory delivery method. It is very fast and very reliable.  It won’t be responsible for duplicate messages.